# How to track questions that have certain tags

Tags: discussion, questions, tracking

Say that I am interested in all questions tagged C++ and I would want something (an application, feed, or whatever) to notify me (by email, IM, desktop notifier, or whatever) as soon as someone asks a question tagged C++. Is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

### https://stackexchange.com/filters/new

[image]

Comment: Well that's convenient.

Comment: Maybe want to blur out email address? I guess, unless it's already public.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of rss feeds.

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c++

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But won't there be considerable delay? Do you use RSS feeds too. What RSS reader do you use for this purpose?

Comment: I personally don't use feeds, but someone who does probably knows how to set it to notify you when it changes. The feeds themselves are pretty up to date. Most feed readers will remember what you've already seen, I don't really see a need to up to date notification of new questions, just check when you have time to spare. There won't be any other solutions to this for awhile/ever.